# How to debug Safari 6.0.5

Tags: safari

I'm currently running Safari 7.0.3 and have been tasked with fixing a layout bug that only appears in Safari 6.0.5. IE dev tools has that handy feature for using an older version of IE, but I'm not sure what to do about Safari, does anyone know of something similar--maybe an extension--or even a site where I could troubleshoot virtually?

Comment: I found this page http://support.apple.com/downloads/#internet but version 6 is not provided, and if it were I'm not sure I'd want to install it alongside 7 if that's even possible.

Comment: I was unable to find a solution, but sometimes a problem stops being a problem if you want long enough. Sorry that's not more helpful.